# MSIX App Attach and Azure Virtual Desktop

Tags: azure, android-virtual-device, msix

I have an Azure Virtual Desktop environment with a host pool and a single session host for testing before being roled out to production (with more session hosts). The session hosts are joined to an AD DS domain and the domain is in sync with Azure AD for both users and devices.

I am using Azure File Shares and FSLOGIX for user profiles which is working perfectly.

I am currently working on setting up several applications with MSIX and I believe I am 99% there. One of the applications I have setup is Notepad++ and when I run the **notepad++.msix** application from my test machine it works. I have then converted the MSIX to VHD and I can mount the VHD manually on my test machine and the app runs without issue.

Now here is where it goes wrong. I uploaded the MSIX app (the VHD) to the Azure file share and linked it to the host pool and app group, however when I login to the session host the VHD doesn't attach automatically so the app never appears for the user. When I manually mount the VHD I can run the app without issue.

The difficultly I'm having is that there are no errors at all, not even in event viewer. So I am not sure why it won't automatically attach the VHD.

At first, I thought it might have been permissions. but doesn't seem to be the case, the computer account and user account are both SMB contributors in RBAC on the share and have read/execute/list at the NTFS level.

Anyone seen this and know where I could be going wrong?

Thanks
Jon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve the issue I was having, I had to make sure that the VM extension that runs the PowerShell script to join the session hosts to the host pool, I needed to use the latest URL which at the time of writing was and it allows MSIX app attach to work correctly.

**https://wvdportalstorageblob.blob.core.windows.net/galleryartifacts/Configuration_09-08-2022.zip**